# How do I add configuration files to repositiory?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, serve-static

I'm a bit new to servers like Nginx/Apache/other servers.

I'm working on a web project, and I want the client to be able to interact with the server. However, the client is on port 3000 and my server is on port 8000. I figured out that I needed a way to serve static files, while also having a reverse proxy. I heard that is what Nginx is for.

In development, I can do something like this with vite.

```
export default defineConfig({
    server:{
        proxy:{
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8000'
        }
    }
})
```

The thing is, vite is for development and not for production. I could probably use `serve`, but that doesn't support reverse proxies, I believe. I could also use Nginx, but the Nginx configuration files are not relative to project, but they are absolute files. I don't like that since I want to add the Nginx config files to my GitHub repo, and it could conflict with other future projects. If there is a way to commit Nginx config files, I would appreciate it if you let me know.

If there are alternatives to Nginx/Apache that I can commit to my project, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just learned of `http-server` from node.js, and it has what I need.

Comment: Please elaborate